# Startup Disk Creator cannot write to brand new USB drive, although I can write normal files

Tags: usb, startup-disk-creator

I'm trying to make an Ubuntu bootable USB drive from a .iso file.

I am following the tutorial at [ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#3-launch-startup-disk-creator)

- Step 3 says, "Launch Startup Disk Creator".
- Step 4 covers "ISO and USB selection"

[image: Make Startup Disk]

---

At this point, it refuses to write to the drive. I thought my USB stick was old, so I bought a brand new one, but same behaviour.

[image: Error]

---

I've tried various incantations suggested on SE or forums, suggesting such things as "umount", etc.

Ultimately, I'm trying a late upgrade from 18.04, and have rendered my system into an unstable state (don't have gparted available) due to packages that will no longer install, so I was going for a fresh install, given that /home/stewart is on an entirely separate disk.

Help!

Comment: How is the USB formatted? Since your computer is in "unstable state" the app may be malfunctioning. If you have access to a Windows or a Mac computer, try to create the startup disk there.

Comment: There seems to be problems due to lacking write permissions. If you can run a terminal window, please try `sudo usb-creator-gtk`, enter your user password, and try again.

Comment: @sudodus  This worked.  If you would like to post as a full answer, I will accept.

Comment: @Stewart, I'm glad that I could help you solve the problem, and now you have a 'full answer'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be problems due to lacking write permissions. `sudo` is the classic way to get elevated permissions in Ubuntu.

If you can run a terminal window, please put the program behind `sudo`

```
sudo usb-creator-gtk
```

enter your user password, and try again.